# How do I print a message when there are updates from a specific channel (pyrogram)?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I receive a message with any new updates but I would like to receive one for a specific channel.

```
@app.on_message(Filters.chat("mychannel"))
def from_pyrogramchat(client, message):
   print("New message in @mychannel")
```

https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram

thanks!

Comment: well. that's the correct filter and it should work. could it be the case that you have another handler and that's getting triggered - not this one?

Comment: i dont think so?  because if I change from (Filters.chat("mychannel")) to (Filters.channel) it works  ...works for all channels tho obv

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new Filter that filters message from a particular channel

```
@Client.on_message(Filters.channel & Filters.create(lambda c,m: m.chat.id == -1001234567890))
async def foo(c, m):
    print(m)
```

reference - [pyrogram doc](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/create-filters)